# How can I update the azure web job trigged timing

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have an existing azure web job but for some changes, I need to update the timing of the azure web job from 10 min to 5min. But in the portal, I did not get any section from where I can update. Do I need to create a new one for that or I can change that form somewhere? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the kudu(Advanced tool), then in the kudu site, go to this location `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\your_webjob`, then in the `settings.job` file, change the timer as per your need.

Steps:

1.in your azure portal -> your web app -> in the left pane, click the "Advanced tools" -> then click the "go" button to enter into the kudu site:

[image]

2.In the kudu site, click the "Debug console" and select CMD, then nav to the location: `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\your_webjob`. -> then find the `settings.job` file, click the edit button:

[image]